# Characterization of the image of the Laplacian

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, laplacian

I'm trying to understand the set of functions  $\mathbb R^3 \rightarrow \mathbb R$ and how the Laplacian interacts with them. Recall that the laplacian $\Delta: (\mathbb R^3 \rightarrow \mathbb R)\rightarrow (\mathbb R^3 \rightarrow \mathbb R)$ is defined as

$$
\Delta(f) \equiv \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial ^2 f}{\partial y^2} + \frac{\partial ^2 f}{\partial z^2}
$$

Now, is there some convenient characterization of the *image* of the Laplacian, the set:

$$
Im(\Delta) \equiv \{ \Delta(f) \mid  f:   \mathbb R^3 \rightarrow \mathbb R \}
$$

Searching for "image of Laplacian" is not useful since it gives me results about image processing that I don't care about!
Is there a nice characterization of the set $Im(\Delta)$?

Comment: Ah, so you're asking a PDE question: For which functions $g \colon \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$ does the [Poisson equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson%27s_equation) $\Delta f = g$ have a solution?

Comment: Can anything useful be said about the space of solutions of the Poisson equation? Is there a nice way to characterize the solution space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for codomain instead. You may like Sec. 4 [here](https://downloads.hindawi.com/journals/jfs/2008/837415.pdf).